# Muon Package manager stuck at 100%

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, lubuntu, muon-package-manager

I've tried to install the Lubuntu desktop package through Muon package manager in Kubuntu 11.10, downloading and installing went fine, however it is stuck at 100%, it's been already 30 mins. and i can't restart the computer as Muon cancels the logout process.

What do i do now?  should i just turn off the computer manually? or just let Muon finish whatever it's doing?, there's no drive activity by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would ...**

If the Muon /1/, /2/ have finished (or crashed) the installation then you could kill the Muon. The KDE has graphical System Activity /3/ screen. You could kill processes with it.

The System Activity should ask the root password if it needs it. Sometimes the password query is under the System Activity window. That is, you need to move the System Activity window to see the password query window.

You could also kill the muon process from the command line. Example:

Starting a konsole and typing:

```
:~$ ps -e | grep muon
 2022 ?        00:00:01 muon
:~$ sudo kill 2022
[sudo] password for User:
```

After this check with the Muon package manager, if there are broken packages or other error messages.

**Links**

1. https://wiki.kubuntu.org/OneiricOcelot/Final/Kubuntu
2. http://jontheechidna.wordpress.com/
3. http://userbase.kde.org/System_Activity

Comment: Thanks, i did end up turning off and restarting the computer thereby killing the process as you said, amazingly all packages were fine, but i just ended up reinstalling them just to make sure.

Comment: sometimes you'll need to delete a lock file too

Answer (score 1):

```
killall muon
sudo killall dpkg
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

The first command ends the Muon package manager.

The second, kills `dpkg`, which is responsible for actually installing the packages.

The third runs `dpkg` in a way where it cleans up and tries to finish installing any packages. Hope this helps!

Comment: It would be more helpful if you would add a bit more information on what those commands do.